# netctl not auto-connecting consistently

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, netctl

I am trying to setup my wifi network in Arch Linux ARM to auto-connect at home and office. But it is not always connecting automatically as intended.

```
netctl list
* wlan0-Spaceship
  wlan0-Cremehead
```

I am not quite sure how to debug this problem as it is acting very randomly. I have enabled both `wlan0-Spaceship` and `wlan0-Cremehead` which i assume should be the most important thing?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to enable the netctl-auto service:

```
$ systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlan0.service
```

But it has not solved the problem, but i see these two `FAIL` statements:

```
$ netctl-auto list
  FAIL
  FAIL

  $ systemctl --type=service
  netctl-auto@wlan0.service             loaded active running Automatic wireless network connection using netctl profiles
  netctl.service                        loaded active exited  (Re)store the netctl profile state
* netctl@wlan0\x2dSpaceship.service   loaded failed failed  Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu
* netctl@wlan0\x2dCremehead.service loaded failed failed  Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just found out that i have problems enabling a connection. I need to do this two times to start.

```
Mar 11 10:05:39 proto-pi2-sandbox network[578]: The WPA supplicant did not start for interface 'wlan0'
Mar 11 10:05:39 proto-pi2-sandbox network[578]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'wlan0-Cremehead'
Mar 11 10:05:39 proto-pi2-sandbox systemd[1]: netctl@wlan0\x2dCremehead.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 10:05:39 proto-pi2-sandbox systemd[1]: Failed to start Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is through `nectl-auto`. `netctl` is for auto connecting on boot or whenever the service through systemd is started where `netctl-auto` connects to the profiles enabled in its own manager and you would only have `netctl-auto@[interface].service` enabled.

[netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl)

[netctl-auto](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#Automatic_switching_of_profiles)

Comment: Would this not create redundancy as there are profiles as services from netctl already?

Comment: See my primary post. I have updated with info!

Comment: So, in your update 2 it looks like you still have the netctl profiles enabled. You should ONLY have the netctl-auto profile enabled and started you should disable all oter netctl profiles. Then use netctl-auto list to make sure your profiles are ready to auto switch with netctl-auto.